# Partial View with self updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I've encountered a problem in my practice project (MVC Music Store). I have made a partial view to search for an artist. I expect the partial view to take no arguments and work on its own.

Partial view in the right half part
[image: Partial view in the right half part]

I have a view specific model for the Artist Search Partial View. The model is as follows:

```
public class ArtistSearch
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> SearchResult { get; set; }

    public ArtistSearch()
    {
        SearchResult=new List<Artist>();
    }
}
```

Controller code is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string query)
        {
            ArtistSearch asResult = new ArtistSearch();
            if (query != null)
            {
                var temp = from a in db.Artists
                           where a.Name.Contains(query)
                           select a;

                asResult.SearchResult = temp.ToList();
                asResult.SearchString = query;
            }
            return PartialView(asResult);
        }
```

The Partial View is as follows:

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.ArtistSearch


<div class="big-search-box">
    <form action="@Url.Action("Search","Artist")" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBox("query", @Model.SearchString, new { @class = "form-control nrb input-lg", placeholder = "Input your search query..." })
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-iconed btn-lg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="big-search-result-info clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">Showing results for <strong>@Model.SearchString</strong>.</div>
    <div class="pull-right"><strong>@Model.SearchResult.Count</strong> artist(s) found.</div>
</div>

<table>
@foreach (var item in @Model.SearchResult)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@item.Id" >
                <img src=@item.PhotoURL alt=@item.Name style="width:100px;height:70px;">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I wish to place this partial view anywhere on the site. Lets say i placed it(using RenderAction) on Artist/Index Controllers View page.

The simple functionality that I'm trying to achieve is that when i click on search it should self update the partial view with search results. Right now it is transferring me to Artist/Search page.

Thanks for the patience.

Comment: is your practice project published, online tutorial or available on GitHub? is yes please add the link for it :) so I can learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Ajax.BeginForm, below is an example:

**Action**

```
   public ActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        ArtistSearch asResult = new ArtistSearch();
        if (query != null)
        {
            var temp = from a in db.Artists
                       where a.Name.Contains(query)
                       select a;

            asResult.SearchResult = temp.ToList();
            asResult.SearchString = query;
        }
        return PartialView("MyParitalView",asResult);
    }
```

**View**

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
     {
       <div class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("query", @Model.SearchString, new { @class = "form-control nrb input-lg", placeholder = "Input your search query..." })
          <div class="input-group-btn">
             <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-iconed btn-lg" />
           </div>
       </div>
    }
     <div id="result"></div>
```

**Parital View : MyParitalView**

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.ArtistSearch
    <div class="big-search-result-info clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">Showing results for <strong>@Model.SearchString</strong>.</div>
        <div class="pull-right"><strong>@Model.SearchResult.Count</strong> artist(s) found.</div>
    </div>

    <table>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.SearchResult)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@item.Id">
                        <img src=@item.PhotoURL alt=@item.Name style="width:100px;height:70px;">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: That worked with slight modification. Had to put all controls of partial view inside div with id result. Thanks for the help.